# jQuery: classes and .each()

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to add classes to elements within a div (.views-row). The problem I'm having is that the .views-row repeats on the page, which is unavoidable, and the elements I'm attempting to style all end up the same classes regardless of whether they should or not. The code probably explains it better:

```
$(".views-row").each(function(){
        if ($((this)" .field-name-field-warning:contains('High')").length) {
            $((this)" .field-name-field-warning").addClass("fault-high");
            $((this)" .field-name-field-warning .field-label").addClass("disappear");
            $((this)" .field-name-field-warning .field-items").addClass("disappear");
        }
        if ($((this) ".field-name-field-warning:contains('Moderate')").length) {
            $((this) ".field-name-field-warning").addClass("fault-moderate");
            $((this) ".field-name-field-warning .field-label").addClass("disappear");
            $((this) ".field-name-field-warning .field-items").addClass("disappear");
        }
});
```

I guess I'm having trouble with the (this) part. Any thoughts?

Thank-you.

Comment: $(this) is going to be the HTML element with the 'views-row' class applied to it.

Comment: What do you expect `$(this)` to do in your current context?

Comment: I expected `$(this)` to refer to each .views-row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select any element within your current one there are two ways.

Using [$().find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find(".field-name-field-warning")
```

By providing a context (which does practically the same as find):

```
$(".field-name-field-warning", $(this))
```

Comment: .find(): what a great method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on the this :

```
$(this).find("selector");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use .each() here when .addClass() will iterate over all elements for you anyway.

You can start by moving to something like this:

```
var containsHigh = $(".views-row .field-name-field-warning:contains('High')")
containsHigh.addClass('fault-high');
containsHigh.find('.field-label, .field-items').addClass('disappear');

var containsModerate = $(".views-row .field-name-field-warning:contains('Moderate')")
containsModerate.addClass('fault-moderate');
containsModerate.find('.field-label, .field-items').addClass('disappear');
```

Then get even fancier by chaining methods like this:

```
var warnings = $(".views-row .field-name-field-warning");
warnings.filter(":contains('High')")
    .addClass('fault-high')
    .find('.field-label, .field-items').addClass('disappear');

warnings.filter(":contains('Moderate')")
    .addClass('fault-moderate')
    .find('.field-label, .field-items').addClass('disappear');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to find element within an element using `this`. You should `find` method for that and `filter` to filter the element in the matched set of elements.

Here is the complete simplified code.

```
$(".views-row").each(function(){
     var $fieldWarning = $(this).find(".field-name-field-warning");
     if($fieldWarning.length){
        if ($fieldWarning.filter(":contains('High')").length) {
            $fieldWarning.addClass("fault-high");
            $fieldWarning.find(".field-label").addClass("disappear");
            $fieldWarning.find(".field-items").addClass("disappear");
        }
        if ($fieldWarning.filter(":contains('Moderate')").length) {
            $fieldWarning.addClass("fault-moderate");
            $fieldWarning.find(".field-label").addClass("disappear");
            $fieldWarning.find(".field-items").addClass("disappear");
        }
     }
});
```

Reference: **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**